# What's the difference between `as.name` and `sym`?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, quosure

I'm trying to wrap my head around standard, non-standard evaluation, quosures, etc. In many examples, I see passed string variable being transformed into `dplyr`-usable form either with `as.name` or with `sym` of `rlang` package.

Are they interchangeable in pipes? What are the cases that will fail for one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:
I could not readily create a scenario where `as.name` fails to work. [Hadley](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/116#issuecomment-298985481) seems to agree that `as.name` might work. Although this is using `select` which really is robust, trying with `group_by` and `summarise` appears to have no difference.

**Robust `select`**:

```
 varName <- "Sepal.Length"
 select(iris, varName) #This works
```

**No difference between `as.name` and `sym`** for several examples I run.

```
iris %>%
    group_by(!!as.name(varName))
iris %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(varName))
```

Attempts to change `encoding`:

```
var1 <- `Encoding<-`(varName, "unknown")
```

Both `as.name` and `sym` still worked.

**Original answer**:

From the docs`?sym`:

> These functions take strings as input and turn them into symbols.

Contrarily to `as.name()`, they convert the strings to the native encoding beforehand.This is necessary because symbols remove silently the encoding mark of strings (see `set_str_encoding()`).

It therefore seems that using `sym` and related functions eliminates the trouble to do with encoding.

Comment: Is it possible to come up with an example, where `as.name` would fail or be detrimental to the following-up command(s)?