# Why does adding by 1 actually add by 2 in Sparklyr when using dynamic variable names?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

When I run the following code, I expect the value of the Sepal_Width_2 column to be Sepal_Width + 1, but it is in fact Sepal_Width + 2. What gives?

```
require(dplyr)
require(sparklyr)

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='/usr/lib/spark')
sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn")

# for this example these variables are hard coded
# but in my actual code these are named dynamically
sw_name <- as.name('Sepal_Width')
sw2 <- "Sepal_Width_2"
sw2_name <- as.name(sw2)

ir <- copy_to(sc, iris)

print(head(ir %>% mutate(!!sw2 := sw_name))) # so far so good
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 6]
# Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species Sepal_Width_2
# <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
# 5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa            3.5
# 4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa            3  
# 4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa            3.2
# 4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa            3.1
# 5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa            3.6
# 5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa            3.9

print(head(ir %>% mutate(!!sw2 := sw_name) %>% mutate(!!sw2 := sw2_name + 1))) # i guess 2+2 != 4?
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 6]
# Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species Sepal_Width_2
# <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
# 5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa            5.5
# 4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa            5  
# 4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa            5.2
# 4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa            5.1
# 5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa            5.6
# 5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa            5.9
```

My use case requires that I use the dynamic variable naming you see above. In this example it is rather silly (compared to just using the variables directly), but in my use case I'm running the same function across hundreds of different spark tables. They all have the same "schema" in terms of the number of columns and what each column is (outputs from some machine learning models), but the names differ because each table contains the output for a different model. The names are predictable, but since they vary, I construct them dynamically as you see here instead of hardcoding them.

It appears that Spark knows how to add 2 and 2 together when the names are hardcoded, but when the names are dynamic it suddenly freaks out.

Comment: Adding by 0.5 allows it to add by 1, but this behavior is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which package was the culprit (sparklyr, dplyr, R, who knows), but this has been fixed when I upgraded from 3.6.3/sparklyr 1.5 to R 4.0.2/sparklyr 1.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

You might be misusing `as.name` which is leading `sparklyr` to misinterpret your input.

Note that your code errors when just working on a local table:

```r
sw_name <- as.name('Sepal.Width') # swap "_" to "." to match variable names
sw2 <- "Sepal_Width_2"
sw2_name <- as.name(sw2)
data(iris)

print(head(iris %>% mutate(!!sw2 := sw_name)))
# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Sepal_Width_2`.
# x object 'Sepal.Width' not found
# i Input `Sepal_Width_2` is `sw_name`.
```

Note that you are using both the `!!` operator from rlang with `as.name` from base R. But you are not using them together as demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870158/whats-the-difference-between-as-name-and-sym) question.

I recommend you use `sym` and `!!` from the rlang package instead of `as.name`, and that you apply both to character strings that are column names. The following works locally, and is consistent with the [non-standard evaluation guidance](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html). So it should translate to spark:

```r
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

sw <- 'Sepal.Width'
sw2 <- paste0(sw, "_2")

head(iris %>% mutate(!!sym(sw2) := !!sym(sw)))
head(iris %>% mutate(!!sym(sw2) := !!sym(sw)) %>% mutate(!!sym(sw2) := !!sym(sw2) + 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The syntax is legal and "works" in Sparklyr in that it runs, however, the odd behavior is still present. I will experiment with different combinations of sym and !! and see what happens. Thank you for linking the non-standard evaluation guidance. It's clear as mud but I'll try to work through it.